# Image not found when replacing background-image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

As a proof of concept, I am attempting to change the background-image of a div using jQuery with the same image as the original.

The original css is:

CSS

```
.content {
  background-image: url("test.jpg");
}
```

jQuery inside a wrapper:

```
$('.content').css("background-image", 'url(test.jpg)');
```

I can see that jQuery is firing off fine, and replaces the image (and have verified in Firebug that the CSS is exactly the same), but for some reason, after the jQuery fires, the browser "Could not load the image".

The computed CSS is exactly the same. If I deselect the in-line rule thrown in by jQuery, the old rule is activated and the image appears.

Why would the browser treat the rule differently when injected in-line vs. when it is in the CSS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing quotes is not the issue. **The issue is the path to the image**.

If the image is in the same folder as the page, then you can use `test.jpg`.

If the images are in a different folder on your site, then you need to include the relative path to that image:

```
$('.content').css("background-image", 'url(../images/test.jpg)');
```

Comment: nada - relative path isn't fixing the problem. My assets are split up by images, js and css. If the CSS path works, I'd expect the path in the JS to be exactly the same.

Comment: No, once the HTML pages has rendered and you want to change the background image, the image path needs to be relative to the HTML page, not the css page.

Comment: I needed a relative root, but the relative root was 'url(../assets/test.jpg)');

Previously, I had tried 'url(../assets/images/test.jpg)');, but this didn't work - my guess is that Rails compiles all assets into a single assets folder.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your jQuery:

```
$('.content').css("background-image", 'url(test.jpg)');
```

should be:

```
$('.content').css("background-image", 'url("test.jpg")');
```

Comment: I removed the quotes in an attempt to get it to work - it isn't changing anything adding them back.

Comment: @Mottie So they don't!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.content').css("background-image", 'url(test.jpg)');
```

Replace with

```
$('.content').css("background-image", 'url("test.jpg")');
```

Notice the lack of quote marks.

Comment: I removed the quotes in an attempt to get it to work - it isn't changing anything adding them back.

Comment: @ajain have you checked your console to see if the path is correct? Remember the relative root will likely be different from within jquery than your CSS/HTML. If this isn't working then there's either a JS error you can act on, or the file location is incorrect.